# Why working with maven archetypes is better than just to duplicate the project itself?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I have watched a video about how to work with maven archetypes in netbeans : from a project "A" an archetype is generated and then another project "B" is generated from that archetype. It was ok as netbeans make it all easy. But now i have to change to eclipse and it seems to be more complicated there. So, before i start i would like to understand why working with maven archetypes worth it and why as "B" is exactly the same as "A".
i could just copy/paste the project and refactor/rename the maven project and it's done! So i think i don't really need such as complicated process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the output of a maven archetype is a new copy to be used as a template for your project. It is almost the same copy each time, you can insert your own groupId, artifactId and version. You could achieve the same result if you downloaded and expanded a template zip, and replaced tour artifact/groupId. Then you would need some catalog and a place to keep the zips etc. Maven just organizes this for you in a simple uniform way. Think of a company which uses the same mechanism for company-specific templates.

Comment: I notice your sentence: "It was easy and it seems to me that the output of this process is nothing but a new copy of the original project from which i generated the archetype". The generated project is NOT a copy of *your* project, it is a copy of the desired archetype   project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i did't mean by the output the archetype but the final project generated from the archetype which is nothing but a copy of the original one.

Comment: ...downloaded and expanded a template zip, and replace artifact/groupId. Then you would need some catalog and a place to keep the zips..  is all that a "simple uniform way" ?! :) i could just copy/paste the project and refactor rename the maven project and it's done !

Comment: Which project dou you want to copy/paste? Each archetype creates a template for some sort of project. Do you mean a previous project created from that archetype? You could, but is that simpler? If Eclipse bothers you, just create your project from the command line and import it in eclipse. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html

Comment: The problem is that i'm not sure if i've asked a stupid question but now i start think it is :) Maybe the conventional way is not always the simplest, that's the point.

Comment: I don't think there'e anything wrong with the question. Regarding simplicity: you go to the command line, type "mvn archetype:generate" and answer 4 questions. This is simple. You don't really need an IDE for this, sure not if you are not comfortable with it.

Comment: there still some things more complicated about to deploy(or to install) the generated archetype in the local repository and make eclipse being up to date and know about it.. will see..if i'm blocked i'll ask another question about that precisely. thanks anyway